# How can I properly use another a module's class in another module in a multi-mod Maven SVN project?

Tags: java, spring, svn, maven, autowired

I'm working on a multi-module maven project for my internship.
I'll call the parent Project A. I'll call the two Modules: Module A and Module B.

What I want to do is import a class from Module A so that I can use the Module A's class in Module B. I'm not sure how to do this, and what exactly happens with what I've done so far.

So, I committed the full project to the SVN, and I am able to add the dependency of Module A into my Module B xml.

My question is, what's exactly happening when I import Module A's class into Module B? Is Maven pulling the class from the SVN that I commited to? If I wanted to edit Module A's class so that it will perform another function in Module B, will I have to re-commit all over again, and re-install? If someone can explain the process, it'd be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Also, I'd like to use @Autowired on a class object from Module A and use it in Module B. I'm not sure if that's possible or not, can someone explain a bit on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, what's exactly happening when I import Module A's
>   class into Module B? Is Maven pulling the class from the SVN that I
>   commited to? If I wanted to edit Module A's class so that it will
>   perform another function in Module B, will I have to re-commit all
>   over again, and re-install?

Maven and SVN are two different things and have nothing to do with each other by default. This is what happens when you call "mvn install" on your parent project:

- Maven will recognize that Module B depends on Module A and therefore will build Module A first
- After compiling Module A, Maven will install the created moduleA.jar in your local Maven repository (usually in C:\Users\/.m2)
- Maven will then compile Module B. It will need the moduleA.jar for this and access it from your local Maven repository
- After compiling Module A, Maven will install the created moduleB.jar in your local Maven repository

All this without ever accessing your SVN.

> Also, I'd like to use @Autowired on a class object from Module A and
>   use it in Module B. I'm not sure if that's possible or not, can
>   someone explain a bit on that?

@Autowired is an annotation provided by the Spring framework. See http://www.springsource.org/tutorials for a couple tutorials on Spring.